# Magento 1.8 cant upgrade to 1.9

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, upgrade, ce-1.9.0.1

Using Magento version 1.8.1.0, i am trying to upgrade to the latest version - ver 1.9.0.1.

Cache is disabled, Compilation is disabled.

When I check for upgrades in Magento Connect it shows the same 1.8 version files and says i already have the latest version.

And even if I try to use community/mage_all_latest I get the same result. 
I wasn't able to find anything that could help me so i am asking for any clue that might point me to a way to fix this.

Comment: So once you click "Check for Upgrades" button you don't see any items in the list below marked yellow? Anything appears in available version column?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.8

1. take a backup of current database and current 1.8 code.
2. download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. remove all folders and files from your 1.8 code (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4. now from your 1.8 merge your following folders into the 1.9

   - Community app/code/community
   - Local app/code/local
   - Media
   - your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/ or app/design/frontend/)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/
   - any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
   - copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.8) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
   - custom js files if any from app/js/.
5. now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. now check the site.it done.

Comment: Had to copy some more files of plugins - but this description of an inplace update helped me a lot to get to a clean update.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend not using Magento Connect to upgrade to the latest version of Magento.

- Backup your files and database
- Copy the files and database to a DEV server, if you do not have a DEV server create separate instance of the installation.
- Use the [latest version of magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)
- Debug

You can follow the official upgrade path [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading)

If you run into problems you cannot figure out or need assistance troubleshooting, take note of any error or issue and create a new post.