# upgrade from magentoconnect doesnt work

Tags: upgrade, magento-connect, version

I've run community/Mage_All_Latest in magentoconnect manager and the module changed to 1.9.0.1 version, however when i go back to admin-panel the magento version at the bottom of the page still says 1.8.0.1. 
Also if i "check for upgrades" in magentoconnect it seems all has been already upgraded.
What is missing?, why the upgrade didn't work.
Already clean cache, log-out, then log-in, etc, etc.-

Comment: clear cache and logout and login admin page.

Comment: you can try by upgrading magento mannualy right

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23951/4556 try this

Comment: i've already checked that article, however i need to upgrade using magentoconnect, it's a huge installation with lots of store-views.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large installation I would not recommend using Magento connect to upgrade.

Ideally you would rysnc your new files into a dev version of your site with a GIT repo that is running (To capture the changes)

```
rsync -avz magento1.9/ path/to/dev/site/
```

The above will over write the core files that need to be upgraded. You can then run the upgrade process.

You can refresh the full process here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database