# Magento Upgrade/Roadmap/Migration from 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento2, upgrade, magento-1.6

As we all know, Magento 2.0 is now available.
Many of us are running an older version of Magento (atm).

In my opinion, we need to build a roadmap to migrate Magento to the newest version.

For older roadmaps/upgrade tips:

**- 1.7 to 1.9:** [Magento upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9)

**- 1.6 to 1.9:**
[Best way to upgrade Magento 1.6.2.0 to 1.9.0.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30688/best-way-to-upgrade-magento-1-6-2-0-to-1-9-0-1)

Did someone already upgraded/migrated magento to the newest version? Do you have any suggestions, tips or marks?

Hopefully we can help each other to upgrade succesfully to the newest version of Magento.

Cheers

Comment: There is documentation [Migration Guide] available at the [official Magento website](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html)

Answer (score 7):

Here is resources what we have so far for migration to Magento 2:

- Official migration M1 to M2 guide -
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html
- Official data migration tool - https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce
- Official tool for extensions code migration help - https://github.com/magento/code-migration
- Various un-official community projects for migration - https://firebearstudio.com/blog/migration-to-magento-2-plans-updates-tools-extensions-tutorials.html

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to **upgrade** Magento 1.x store to Magento 2, but it is possible to **migrate data** from an existing Magento 1.x store to a new Magento 2 store.
There is the official data migration tool: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce
And there is the guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can upgrade magento 2 via admin because it does not required many technical knowledge. Follow guide and migrate data. However, it hides many errors.
if you are using Magento EE or Magento go, the best way is finding a Magento migration service. Don't need time and human to read document, research to migrate data. Magento 1.9 and Magento 2 have many differences in structures and systems. Upgrade to Magento 2 is not simple as a quick fix at all.

Comment: Really ? From admin !

Comment: You cannot. M2 is completely different from M1. It's like a new platform, but they just named it Magento for marketing's sake.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed roadmap how replatform to Magento 2 here https://m1-to-m2-migration.com/how-to-upgrade
You need tech skills and experience of many types site migration (domen migration, http->https, etc.).