# How to upgrade magento 1.8.1.0 to magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade, upgrade-script

I am in a need to upgrade my magento store from v1.8.1.0 to v1.9.2.4.

Can anyone please tell me the way to achieve this?

What are the stuffs needed to be taken care of?
NOTE: I am using nginx server.

Is there any script developed by someone so as to achieve this in less time?

Comment: check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Comment: also check here  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23951/21339

Comment: Thanks Arunendra for suggesting Pradeep Sanku answer which can help me to plan for an upgrade

Comment: @PradeepSanku :Is there any suggestion to take care for third party extensions, why because magento 1.9.2.4 covers the patch SUPEE-6788 and I think after upgrading to this version, if any of the third party extension is having admin route compatibility issue then that extension will not work.

Also, bad controller may create issue for some extensions.

can anyone please comment on these points?