# Magento Upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

I want to upgrade existing shop from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.3.2

What are the steps should be followed to accomplish this work?

Comment: Follow simple steps https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow of this official documentation

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html

Comment: Thanks for Answering. But, I found to links for upgrade in magento website:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html and 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html
Which one should i follow?

Comment: Please read simple way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/magento-1-8-cant-upgrade-to-1-9

Comment: Hello; i followed all the steps in the link above. But when trying to access to my shop i get this: SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js

Please could you help me to fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the Steps**

**Step1:-** First, check that core file is change or not using below link

**Link:-**https://blog.amasty.com/freebie-magento-modified-core-files-report-by-amasty/

This step for only security person you can skip this if you don't change anything in Magento Core Files.

**Step2: -** Upload Magento 1.8 Database in PHPMyAdmin

**Step3: -** Setup Magento 1.9.3 and while installation Select Magento 1.8 Database

**Step 4: -** Take Custom Modules and Extensions files[1.App 2.Skin 3.Js] from Old Magento

This is the best and Secure way to Upgrade Magento

Comment: Thanks for Answering. For the 4 th step, it will be after Magento 1.8 Installation? and please could you specify files and directories i have to copy from (App- Skin -JS).

Comment: for specific extension or module they define name also.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you. I'm a beginner in Magento

Comment: suppose a module namespace abc and module name is xyz than related to that the naming convention is used to all in app, skin and js

Comment: Ok. Sorry for Basic questions but i copied all files and i get problems. now i'm in step when i should copy (your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/ or app/design/frontend/)). Should i copy all the content of frontend or just my theme. and how can i know my default theme in 1.8. Sorry again

Comment: you want to take 1.9 files and 1.8 database you not need to copy any thing